# ClipGrab was removed automatically from my PC and i coudn't install anymore

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, 15.10

I did the following steps:

1. `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:clipgrab-team/ppa`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install clipgrab`

But the terminal result was:

```
Package clipgrab is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'clipgrab' has no installation candidate
```

Please help me. Thank You!

[→ Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmItx.png)

Comment: That PPA doesn't exist for 15.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download ClipGrab from the [**clipgrab.org**](http://clipgrab.org/) website.

**Extract** the downloaded **compressed** clipgrab file.

Open the extracted folder and click on `clipgrab`.

The application will launch and is ready to be used.

The tool is portable ... so there is nothing to install.

## Information for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS :

Currently the `clipgrab` executable doesn't launch.

But it is available for **Xenial** from the [ClipGrab PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eclipgrab-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

Comment: @JoydebRoy : You're welcome - enjoy ubuntu experience ! :)